# Is V(select("id")) possible

Tags: gremlin

I would like to modify properties on multiple vertices without using long traversals (see http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#long-traversals). For performance reasons, I have a local cache of vertex IDs.

I would like to do a code like (on Tinkerpop 3.3.3):

```
var list = [ ["id": 123, "prop": "foo"], ["id": 456, "prop": "bar"] ];
g.inject(list)
    .unfold()
    .as("map")
    .V(__.select("id"))
    .property("prop", __.select("map").select("prop"))
    .iterate();
```

But I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected an id that is convertible to Long but received class com.dcbrain.flowengine.dsl.DefaultFlowEngineTraversal
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph$DefaultIdManager$1.convert(TinkerGraph.java:587)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph.lambda$createElementIterator$4(TinkerGraph.java:316)
```

Is there any workaround or does another Tinkerpop version support this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way to create the query:

```
var map= [ 123 : "foo"], [456 : "bar"];
g.withSideEffect("map", map)
    .V(map.keySet().toArray())
    .as("id")
    .property("prop", __.select("map").select(__.select("id").by(T.id)))
    .iterate();
```